# How to fetch from MySQL database “Hindi” (Indian local language) हिन्दी text in websites

Tags: php, mysql

**How to fetch from MySQL database “Hindi” (Indian local language) हिन्दी text in websites**

[pictureofdatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Udjw.png)

when i fetch data from database it show

```
???????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????
??????????????????????????????????????
??????????????????????????????????????
```

**Referring to this question I have changed my database charset to "utf8_unicode_ci", but Still not working. I have written following code to fetch the data**

connection.php page

```
<?php

    $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DB_USER = 'xxxxxxxx_usr';
    $DB_PASS = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $DB_NAME = 'xxxxxxxs_dta';

    try{
        $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);
        $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

index.php page

```
<?php include("../header.php"); ?><style>
    .wrapper{position:relative;}
    .right,.left{width:50%; position:absolute;}
    .right{right:0;}
    .left{left:0;}
</style>    <?php

    require_once 'connect.php';?>
<link href='/Lang/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<?php 

 $iddd =$_GET['id'];
$d = $browser_t; ?>

<div class="content">
<div class="dta">   
    <?php
     mysqi_set_charset( $DB_con, 'utf8');
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT id, title, post, viewers, author, external FROM getpost  WHERE id =:vid');

      $stmt->execute(array(':vid'=>$iddd));
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($row);
            ?>

    <div class="list_item"><h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?> Tutorials</h2></div>

<div class="nykfont"> </div>
<?php echo $row['post']; ?>

<div class="content">
<div class="dta">   
<div class="nykfont"> 
    <div class="lis_ite"><?php echo $row['external']; ?></div>

    <div class="listt_itemm">Author<h5><a href="http://www.mrtutorials.net/Author/<?php echo $row['author']; ?>"><?php echo $row['author']; ?></a></h5></div></div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    else

        ?>

</div></div>
<hr>

    <?php include("../footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Hindi is not local. its national language

Comment: Have you set your encoding to utf-8 in the meta-tag in your index.php?

Comment: yes i  have set but not work

Comment: You could try using utf8mb4 rather than utf8 in MySQL. Since MySQL 5.5.3 it is used to remove the limitation of characters which was set to xFFFD in utf8

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my same problem.

`ALTER TABLE tablename 
CHANGE COLUMN columnname VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8'  ;`

hope solve yours too.